# Analog dinosaur needs simple buzzer when timed power source ceases

Tags: relay, timer, delay

OK, as my profile states, my electronics knowledge is extremely limited and so is my use of correct terminology and symbology considering I come from a mechanical background.

I'm adding liquid agitation to my 3D printer's modified wash station, and I'd like to add an audible signal when the timed wash cycle is complete.  I have a cheap timer from Amazon that does what I want based on my breadboard experiments.

To keep things simple I'm using all 12VDC components.

What I had in mind was to use the 12VDC that runs the agitators to also charge up a capacitor that will be used to activate the alarm when the power is discontinued at the end of the wash cycle (typically 15-minutes).

My idea is to use a 12VDC automotive relay (have plenty) to hold open the switch contacts when energized.  When the wash cycle is over, the switch contacts close dumping the capacitor's charge to the alarm for 10 - 30 seconds.  Would my simple circuit do the job?

At this point in time I have no idea what the Farad rating of the capacitor or the OHM's value of the resistor or potentiometer should be.

[image]

---

Now that the holidays are over and life (e.g. unexpected house repairs) have been completed for the time being; I have had a chance to calculate and understand this stuff better, or at least I think so.  Thanks to 'Transistor' for the 'Must Calculate' link!

I have two buzzers in mind that I found at Digi-Key.  CPE-253 or CPI-42533C-120.  For a 10-second discharge I calculated anywhere from 5mF to 11mF depending on the buzzer.  I can get those capacitors at Digi-Key for reasonable prices; but I see what both of you're saying about needing a big capacitor.  The buzzer might be omitted.

Comment: Are you able to buy a transistor as well as the big capacitor you'd need? If you can use a capacitor, transistor and three resistors, the problem's much easier and the capacitor far smaller and practical.

Comment: If it's available on Digi-Key, I can buy it provided the cost is within reason.  What I'm trying to accomplish is first get validation I'm on the right track before buying all sorts of stuff I may or may not use in the future.  Thanks for your help, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find a low-power 12 V buzzer and hook it up to a 12 V source and measure the current required using your multimeter. Let's say it's 12 mA.
2. From Ohm's law work out the equivalent resistance of the buzzer. \$ R = \frac {V}{I} \$. For 12 V and 12 mA that would be 1 kΩ.
3. Let's get a rough idea of the capacitance required from the RC time constant formula \$ \tau = RC \$. (This tells us the time it takes to charge or discharge a capacitor by 63%.) Setting \$ \tau \$ = 20 s we get \$ C = \frac {20}{1k} = 20 \ \mathrm {mF} \$ (20,000 µF)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnhaXn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Suggested circuit.*

How it works:

- When the relay is energised C1 charges up to 12 V. R1 limits the charge current to 0.12 A to prevent a sudden load on the supply on power-up. It will dissipate \$ \frac {V^2}{R} = \frac {12^2}{100} = 1.44 \ \mathrm W \$ for a moment on power-up but a 1/2 W resistor should be OK.
- When the relay switches off the capacitor will discharge through the buzzer.

See [Must Calculate](http://mustcalculate.com/electronics/capacitorchargeanddischarge.php) to assist with RC calculations.

Comment: Yep! you need a very big capacitor. If mjncad would have a permanent 5..12V source somewhere the circuit could be made much smaller.

Comment: OK, I can understand this circuit, and it corrects my component placement in the circuit.  I am using a permanent 120VAC to 12VDC power supply in my setup as I don't want the hassle of batteries.  I need to study this when I'm awake instead of close to bedtime.  Thanks!